# SELECT multiple table and put them in the same format as the first one

Tags: sql

i want to bring out a table made of other table with a specific format which is already defined

i already did this so the empty one are replace by **"--"**:

```
INSERT INTO 
`saisie_support_general`
(`Categorie`, `Urgence`, `Code_CM`, `Type`, `S_Type`, `Details`, `Date`, `Status`, `Acteurs`, `Semaine`, `Date_fin`, `Resolution`, `Date_Modif`, `Date_Modif_Saisie`, `Matricule_creation`, `Matricule_Modif`)
 SELECT
    `Categorie` as `Categorie`,
    `Urgence` as `Urgence`,
    `Code_CM` as `Code_CM`,
    '--' as `Type`,
    '--' as `S_Type`,
    CONCAT(`EAN`,' ', `SIGMA`,' ',`Libelle`,' ',`Famille_Actuelle`,' ',`Famille_Souhaitee`) as `Details`,
    '--' as `Date`,
    '--' as `Status`,
    '--' as `Acteurs`,
    '--' as `Semaine`,
    '--' as `Date_fin`,
    '--' as `Resolution`,
    '--' as `Date_Modif`, 
    '--' as `Date_Modif_Saisie`,
    '--' as `Matricule_creation`,
    '--' as `Matricule_Modif` 
    FROM `table_x` WHERE 1`
```

This is one of the 5 sql select I plan to add to the table

I want to keep the "**INSERT INTO**" but at each call the table was filled with all of what was inside.

Is it possible to make a temporary table ?
Or is it possible to only keep the last iteration of the table ? I tried several things but my brain blocked and decided not to work anymore when he think about sql.

Thx.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to make a temporary table and each RDBMS has it's own way of doing so. Talking about iteration, yes you could do that, but what if there are changes or exclusion in any previous records? Which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using Phpmyadmin

Comment: Since you have a Date field you could use that as reference. Something like `select Data from saisie_support_general ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1` and then using the result of this query in here `...FROM table_x WHERE table_x.Date > result_of_first_query`.

Comment: Was that of any help?